# Shred JSON array into child tables using SQL Server functions

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server

Here is JSON I would like to shred into three tables using SQL Server JSON functions:

```
   { 
        "school" : "Ecole",
        "classes": [
         {
          "className": "Math",
          "Students": ["LaPlace", "Fourier","Euler","Pascal"]
         }
         {
          "className": "Science",
          "Students": ["Newton", "Einstein","Al-Biruni", "Cai"]
         },
        ]
    }

    Table 1
    +-------+--------+  
    | ID    | school |
    +-------+--------+

    Table 2
    +-------+---------------+-----------+  
    | ID    | schoolID (FK) | className |
    +-------+---------------+-----------+  

    Table 3
    +-------+---------------+-----------+  
    | ID    | classID (FK)  | student   | 
    +-------+---------------+-----------+
```

My queries so far:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.school') --Returns the name of the school

SELECT
   ClassName = JSON_VALUE(c.value, '$.className'), 
   Students = JSON_QUERY(c.value, '$.Students') 
FROM
   OPENJSON(@json, '$.classes') c
```

-- Returns the name of the class and a JSON array of students.

I am wondering how use SQL to shred the JSON array to extract the data for the third table so that it looks like this:

Math class Id = 1
Science class Id =2

```
   Id     ClassId   Student
 +-------+--------+-----------+  
 | 1     | 1      | LaPlace   | 
 +-------+--------+-----------+  
 | 2     | 1      | Fourier   | 
 +-------+--------+-----------+  
 | 3     | 1      | Euler     | 
 +-------+--------+-----------+  
 | 4     | 1      | Pascal    | 
 +-------+--------+-----------+  
 | 5     | 2      | Newton    | 
 +-------+--------+-----------+  
 | 6     | 2      | Einstein  | 
 +-------+--------+-----------+  
 | 7     | 2      | Al-Biruni |  
 +-------+--------+-----------+  
 | 8     | 2      | Cai       | 
 +-------+--------+-----------+
```

I can get the Ids from the other tables, but I don't know how to write a query to extract the students from the JSON arrays.

I do have the ability to restructure the JSON schema so that instead of arrays of strings, I could make arrays of objects:

```
"Students": [{"StudentName"}:"Newton", {"StudentName":"Einstein"},{"StudentName":"Al-Biruni"}, {"StudentName":"Cai"}]
```

But I am not certain that makes it any easier. Either way, I would still like to know how to write a query to accomplish the first case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = N'
  { 
        "school" : "Ecole",
        "classes": [
         {
          "className": "Math",
          "Students": ["LaPlace", "Fourier","Euler","Pascal"]
         },
         {
          "className": "Science",
          "Students": ["Newton", "Einstein","Al-Biruni", "Cai"]
         }
        ]
    }
';


with q as
(
SELECT
   ClassID = c.[key]+1,
   ClassName = JSON_VALUE(c.value, '$.className'), 
   Id = row_number() over (order by c.[Key], students.[key] ),
   Student = students.value
FROM
   OPENJSON(@json, '$.classes') c
cross apply openjson(c.value,'$.Students') students
)
select Id, ClassId, Student
from q


/*
Id          ClassId     Student
----------- ----------- -----------
1                    1           LaPlace
2                    1           Fourier
3                    1           Euler
4                    1           Pascal
5                    2           Newton
6                    2           Einstein
7                    2           Al-Biruni
8                    2           Cai
*/
```

Comment: JSON_VALUE and openjson work in which version of SQL Server.

Comment: SQL Server 2016+ and Azure SQL Database.

Comment: David, thanks! Can you recommend a good resource for learning more about SQL in general, including the new ability to query JSON?

Comment: Here's the "official" hub, although there's tons of third-party content out there too.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/sql-training.aspx

Answer (score 2):

`JSON` is supported starting with SQL-Server 2016.

As your JSON is deeper nested (array of classes contains an array of students) I'd solve this with a combination of `OPENJSON` and a `WITH`-clause. Please look a bit closer to the `AS JSON` in the `WITH`-clause. This will allow for another `CROSS APPLY OPENJSON()`, hence moving deeper and deeper into your JSON-structure.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
N'{ 
    "school" : "Ecole",
    "classes": [
     {
      "className": "Math",
      "Students": ["LaPlace", "Fourier","Euler","Pascal"]
     },
     {
      "className": "Science",
      "Students": ["Newton", "Einstein","Al-Biruni", "Cai"]
     }
    ]
}';
```

--The query

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY B.className,C.[key]) AS RowId
      ,A.school
      ,B.className
      ,CASE B.className WHEN 'Math' THEN 1 WHEN 'Science' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END AS ClassId
      ,C.[key] AS StudentIndex
      ,C.[value] AS Student    
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH(school NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,classes NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) A
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(A.classes)
WITH(className NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,Students NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) B
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(B.Students) C
```

The result

```
+-------+--------+-----------+---------+--------------+-----------+
| RowId | school | className | ClassId | StudentIndex | Student   |
+-------+--------+-----------+---------+--------------+-----------+
| 1     | Ecole  | Math      | 1       | 0            | LaPlace   |
+-------+--------+-----------+---------+--------------+-----------+
| 2     | Ecole  | Math      | 1       | 1            | Fourier   |
+-------+--------+-----------+---------+--------------+-----------+
| 3     | Ecole  | Math      | 1       | 2            | Euler     |
+-------+--------+-----------+---------+--------------+-----------+
| 4     | Ecole  | Math      | 1       | 3            | Pascal    |
+-------+--------+-----------+---------+--------------+-----------+
| 5     | Ecole  | Science   | 2       | 0            | Newton    |
+-------+--------+-----------+---------+--------------+-----------+
| 6     | Ecole  | Science   | 2       | 1            | Einstein  |
+-------+--------+-----------+---------+--------------+-----------+
| 7     | Ecole  | Science   | 2       | 2            | Al-Biruni |
+-------+--------+-----------+---------+--------------+-----------+
| 8     | Ecole  | Science   | 2       | 3            | Cai       |
+-------+--------+-----------+---------+--------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Also a good answer since the CASE can be used to set other values for the Math and Science Ids.